# Some errors when I start Moqui

Tags: java, postgresql, moqui

I am new to Moqui. I start moqui with these commands:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/moqui/moqui-framework.git moqui
$ cd moqui
$ ./gradlew getComponent -Pcomponent=PopCommerce
$ ./gradlew getComponent -Pcomponent=HiveMind
$ ./gradlew downloadElasticSearch
$ ./gradlew load
```

And I have some problems:

```
20:33:03.043 ERROR main .moqui.i.e.EntityDatasourceFactoryImpl Error connecting to DataSource transactional (postgres), try 4 of 5: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception bitronix.tm.internal.BitronixRuntimeException: error initializing JdbcProxyFactory [in thread "main"]

20:32:52.683  WARN c-jmx-worker b.tm.u.ManagementRegistrar Cannot execute ManagementRegisterCommand on object with name bitronix.tm:type=JDBC,UniqueName=transactional_DS,Id=4

20:32:36.567 ERROR  main .moqui.i.e.EntityDatasourceFactoryImpl Error connecting to DataSource transactional (postgres), try 1 of 5: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: 
Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @56620197
```

Here is my file MoquiDefaultConf.xml:

```xml
<default-property name="instance_purpose" value="production"/>

<!-- Locale and Time Zone Properties -->
<default-property name="default_locale" value="en_US"/>
<default-property name="default_time_zone" value="US/Pacific"/>
<default-property name="database_time_zone" value="US/Pacific"/>

<!-- Web App Properties -->
<default-property name="webapp_http_host" value=""/>
<default-property name="webapp_http_port" value=""/>
<default-property name="webapp_https_port" value=""/>
<default-property name="webapp_https_enabled" value="false"/>
<default-property name="webapp_allow_origins" value=""/>
<default-property name="webapp_handle_cors" value="true"/>
<default-property name="webapp_status_ips" value="127.0.0.1"/>
<default-property name="webapp_require_session_token" value="true"/>
<default-property name="webapp_upload_executable_allow" value="false"/>
<default-property name="webapp_client_ip_header" value=""/>

<!-- Properties for the primary (transactional group) datasource -->
<default-property name="entity_ds_db_conf" value="postgres"/>
<default-property name="entity_ds_host" value="127.0.0.1"/>
<default-property name="entity_ds_port" value="5432"/>
<default-property name="entity_ds_database" value="h2"/>
<default-property name="entity_ds_url" value="jdbc:h2:${moqui_runtime}/db/h2/${entity_ds_database};lock_timeout=30000"/>
<default-property name="entity_ds_schema" value=""/>
<default-property name="entity_ds_user" value="postgres"/>
<default-property name="entity_ds_password" value="trunghung0804"/>
<default-property name="entity_ds_crypt_pass" value="MoquiDefaultPassword:CHANGEME"/>
<default-property name="entity_ds_crypt_pass_old" value="MoquiDefaultPassword:CHANGEME"/>
<default-property name="entity_add_missing_runtime" value="false"/>
<default-property name="entity_add_missing_startup" value="true"/>
<default-property name="entity_lock_track" value="false"/>
<default-property name="entity_statement_timeout" value="false"/>
<default-property name="entity_empty_db_load" value="seed,seed-initial,install"/>
```

And my datasource configuration in MoquiDefaultConf.xml:

```xml
<datasource group-name="transactional" database-conf-name="${entity_ds_db_conf}" schema-name="${entity_ds_schema}"
        runtime-add-missing="${entity_add_missing_runtime}" startup-add-missing="${entity_add_missing_startup}">
    <!-- by default no inline-jdbc or jndi-jdbc elements, use default from database conf -->
</datasource>
<datasource group-name="transactional" database-conf-name="postgres" schema-name="">
    <inline-jdbc pool-minsize="5" pool-maxsize="50">
        <xa-properties user="postgres" password="trunghung0804" pinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection="true"
                       serverName="127.0.0.1" port="5432" databaseName="moqui" autoReconnectForPools="true"
                       useUnicode="true" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    </inline-jdbc>
</datasource>
```

And here is database I connect to:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtcEK.png)

Comment: The error suggest that moqui doesn't support your Java version. Recent versions of Java have tightened things down. You probably need an earlier Java version (e.g. Java 11, maybe even Java 8).

Comment: You didn't mention adding the Postgres JDBC driver... is that on the classpath (in runtime/lib or elsewhere)?

Answer (score 0):

your connection configuration is wrong, use this config

```
<datasource group-name="transactional" database-conf-name="postgres" schema-name="public" startup-add-missing="true" runtime-add-missing="false">
        <inline-jdbc jdbc-uri="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/moqui" jdbc-username="dbUsername" jdbc-password="dbPassword"/>
```

Replace moqui with your database name,

Replace dbUsername with your database username,

Replace dbPassword with your database password